# Angular 8 Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a HTMLCanvasElement in typescript that i want to print but i get a error 
**ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.**

found some threads about setting crossorigin but HTMLCanvasElement dont have a crossorigin in typescript. How can i bypass this problem and get canvas.toDataURL() to work in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was CORS. I had to proxy the data