# HTML2canvas in offline version - Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: javascript, openlayers, html2canvas

I am getting the error:

**Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
at HTMLAnchorElement.**

[image]

and I don't know why, since I added the `crossOrigin = 'anonymous'` to my code both in JavaScript and the HTML code as per the advice below:

['toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984372/todataurl-on-htmlcanvaselement-tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported)

https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/q1pezv2j/

I think the situation is similar to this one:

["Tainted canvases may not be exported" issue still present after setting cross-origin on S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918263/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported-issue-still-present-after-setting-cross-o)

Now, my code looks like this:

```
  <script>
  function makeScreenshot() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("screenshot"), {scale: 2}).then(canvas => {
    canvas.id = "map";
    canvas.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    while (main.firstChild) {
   main.removeChild(main.firstChild); 
    }
    console.log(main);
    main.appendChild(canvas);
    });
    }

    document.getElementById("a-make").addEventListener('click', function()
   {
document.getElementById("a-make").style.display = "none";
makeScreenshot();
document.getElementById("a-download").style.display = "inline";
   }, false);

   document.getElementById("a-download").addEventListener('click', function()
   {
  this.href = document.getElementById("map").querySelector('canvas').toDataURL();
 this.download = "canvas-image.png";
 }, false);
    </script>
```

and the HTML section:

```
     </div>
    <div id="map" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <div id="screenshot" crossorigin>
        <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
            <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
            <div id="popup-content"></div>
     </div>
        </div>
     <a id="a-make" href="#">Make a screenshot</a>
     <a id="a-download" href="#" style="display:none;">Download a screenshot</a>
     </div>
```

The "crossorigin" didn't help. Is there any other solution for this?

Is it related to the domain situation?

[Tainted canvases may not be exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710627/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported)

If the problem is CORS like here:

[Angular 8 Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054694/angular-8-failed-to-execute-todataurl-on-htmlcanvaselement-tainted-canvases)

I use Google Chrome browser, like in the situation below:

[Chrome: Tainted canvases may not be exported; Offline-only app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275740/chrome-tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported-offline-only-app)

but the problem is, that I cannot place the data inside the , because in my case is `<div id="map"></div>`

SOme of the solutions require temporary hosting for this:

[Canvas.toDataURL() Tainted canvases may not be exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59114212/canvas-todataurl-tainted-canvases-may-not-be-exported)

the CORS issues have been explained here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

but it still applies to the image  not to  situation.

Basically, I need something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mvjuhkwq/

but the  in my case comes from another script, based in the separated file, which is linked to my code:

```
     <script src="./resources/qgis2web.js"></script>
```

instead of placing in the container on the index.html file.

I want to launch this script offline and make it useful offline only. Is it possible?

**UPDATE:**

I also added the `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` to the qgis2web.js file

```
 var map = new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults({attribution:false}).extend([
    expandedAttribution,new ol.control.ScaleLine({}),new measureControl(),new 
  geolocateControl()
   ]),
   target: document.getElementById('map'),
   renderer: 'canvas',
   crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
   overlays: [overlayPopup],
   layers: layersList,
   format: 'image/png',
   view: new ol.View({
     maxZoom: 22, minZoom: 17
  })
});
```

still without the result

Comment: If OpenLayers is creating the canvas you need to specify `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` in the layer source(s) https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_XYZ.html

Comment: I've added already and updated my query. Unfortunately still with no result.

Comment: It must be in the `ol.source.???` options for each layer, it is not an option for `ol.Map`.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem with this configuration:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("screenshot"), {
    allowTaint: true,
    foreignObjectRendering: true,

    // your configurations
    scale: 2
}).then(canvas => {...});
```